# Rename a set of files using the information present in a txt file

Tags: c#, list, rename

I have some doubts about how to approach a problem of renaming a set of pdf files according to the information present in a txt file. For example, imagine that in the txt file the following data are separated by tabs:

```
"2222" "_" "Z1" "001" "E" "07"

"2222" "_" "C1" "002" "F" "08"

"2222" "_" "D1" "003" "F" "09"
```

The number of pdf files in a given folder always corresponds to the number of lines in the txt file.
How to change the names of * pdf files using this information in the txt file that is in the same folder where the pdfs are, withou the quotes?

Comment: Could you maybe give an example of what the expected output is supposed to be?

Comment: I have a folder with a lot of files like: 001.pdf, 002.pdf, 003.pdf and one txt file with the values that I put in the first post. I want to rename pdf files using the strings in that txt file. First line of the txt file has the name of the pdf file (without quotes). Second line will be the name of the second pdf file, and so on.

Comment: So for `"2222" "_" "Z1" "001" "E" "07"` what would your expected filename be?

Comment: Yes. That will be the name of the first pdf (001) without that quotes. "2222" "_" "C1" "002" "F" "08" will be the name of the second, and so on.

Comment: How do you know what file to rename? or does it not matter?

Comment: Number of pdf files are the same as txt lines. Pdfs comes with a sequence name like 001.pdf, 002.pdf and sequence lines on txt file matchs the number of pdf files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code as a starting point, and make it more complex if necessary. I have comments to help follow along. Remember to include "using System.IO;".

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string directory = @"E:\TempFiles\"; //Name of directory containing text files and PDFs

        //Get text file with names for PDFs...
        string filenames = File.ReadAllText(directory + "names.txt");

        //Removed quotes, but can be done differently, and split by space, which may not work for all your cases, but gets going in the right direction...
        string[] listFilenames = filenames.Replace("\"", "").Split('\t');

        int i = 0; //Used to access list of filnames...
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(directory))
        {
            //Skip text file...
            if (!file.EndsWith(".txt"))
            {
                //Rename file...
                File.Move(file, directory + listFilenames[i] + ".pdf");
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cardi DeMonaco Jr. Let me try it.

Comment: it rename those files, but name is wrong. The name of first pdf is: _.pdf. Second is: 222.pdf and third is: Z1.pdf

Comment: What should the name of the first PDF be then?

Comment: There is currently no correlation between the names in the text file, and the PDFs in the directory. You would need to implement some sort of sorting somewhere. The order of files in Directory.GetFiles(string) is not guaranteed. Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2) to learn more.

Comment: First one must be: 2222_Z1001E07.pdf